# Is Dhruva portrayed as a devotee of Prajapati Brahma in any texts?

Tags: scripture, brahma, identification-request, dhruva

Dhruva is usually known as a devotee of Lord Vishnu. However, according to some of my relatives, Dhruva was a devotee of Lord Brahma. Do any text portray Dhruva to be a devotee of Lord Brahma?

Comment: Dhruva was also Vishnu devotee in his previous birth. Never heard him as devotee of Brahma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few versions of **Brahma Purana** in [Creation chapter](http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/brahma_purana/more_creation.html) says:

> Uttanapada's son was the Dhruva. Dhruva performed very severe penace (tapasya) for three thousand years. Brahma was so pleased at this that he granted Dhruva an eternal place in the sky, near the constellation that is known as saptarshi or the seven sages. This is the constellation is Ursa Majoris and Dhruva is the pole Star.

**Note:** All the versions of Brahma Purana doesn't mention this story, I have one copy in Hindi and didn't find this story. However the above story is supported in Brahma Purana by [gita-society](http://www.gita-society.com/scriptures/ALL18MAJORPURANAS.IGS.pdf) too, please check page number 2.

It should be noted that all versions of **Vishnu Purana** (by [sacred-texts](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp047.htm), [gita-society](http://www.gita-society.com/scriptures/ALL18MAJORPURANAS.IGS.pdf) (page 93) and [this](http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/vishnu_purana/dhruva_pleases_god_with_his_penance.html)) say that

> Thus receiving a boon from Lord Vishnu, Dhruva occupied a fixed position in the northern sky. Even the sage like Shukracharya praises Dhruva that how fortunate he is.... that even Saptarishis go around him? That pivotal position of Dhruva would continue even in the ages to come.

It might be possible that these stories are from different different Kalpa and both are true. It may also be possible that either version of above mentioned Puranas was edited later.